# How do I automatically resize the content in a grid so that it fits on al resolutions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was submitting this piece of XAML code (a simon game) for a class project, and the Windows couldn't resize to a smaller resolution, so I was wondering if you could help me, I've tried to use *s and autos in my Grid.Columns and Rows but it only seeems to resize the content vertically, not horizontally.

I'm quite new to WPF so if anyone can help me I would appreciate it.

```
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimonWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Simon" Height="1080" Width="1920"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White"
               >

        <!--STYLING-->
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="HeadingStyle">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Nexa Demo"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,40"/>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="SubheadingStyle">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Nexa Demo"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,-50,8,8"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <!--STYLING-->



        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheadingStyle}" Name="SimonStatus"
                   Text="WATCH" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="280,20"/>


        <!--HEADING-->


        <Grid Width="777" Height="777">
            <!--COLUMN DEFINITIONS-->
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="350*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="350*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="350*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="70*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="350*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--COLUMN DEFINITIONS-->

            <!--STYLING-->
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Setter Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientOrigin>0.5,0.5</RadialGradientBrush.GradientOrigin>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Center>0.5,0.5</RadialGradientBrush.Center>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RadiusX>0.5</RadialGradientBrush.RadiusX>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RadiusY>0.5</RadialGradientBrush.RadiusY>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Opacity>0</RadialGradientBrush.Opacity>
                                <GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop.Color>White</GradientStop.Color>
                                    <GradientStop.Offset>0</GradientStop.Offset>
                                </GradientStop>
                                <GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop.Color>Blue</GradientStop.Color>
                                    <GradientStop.Offset>1.9</GradientStop.Offset>
                                </GradientStop>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <!--STYLING-->

            <!--GRADIENT SECTION-->
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
                       Fill="Blue"
                       RadiusX="0,100"
                       RadiusY="0,55"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
                       Name="BlueBlock"
                       RadiusX="0,100"
                       RadiusY="0,55">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush 
                        x:Name="BlueBlockGradient"
                        GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                        Center="0.5,0.5"
                        RadiusX="0.5"
                        RadiusY="0.5"
                        Opacity="0">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"
                                      x:Name="WhiteStop4"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1.9"
                                       x:Name="BlueStop"/>

                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>


            <!--GRADIENT SECTION-->
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"
                       Fill="Orange"
                        RadiusX="0,100"
                       RadiusY="0,55"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"
                       Name="OrangeBlock"
                       RadiusX="0,100"
                       RadiusY="0,55">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush 
                        x:Name="OrangeBlockGradient"
                        GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                        Center="0.5,0.5"
                        RadiusX="0.5"
                        RadiusY="0.5"
                        Opacity="0">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"
                                      x:Name="WhiteStop3"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="1.9"
                                       x:Name="OrangeStop"/>

                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>





            <!--GRADIENT SECTION-->
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
                       Fill="Green"
                        RadiusX="0,100"
                       RadiusY="0,55"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
                       Name="GreenBlock"
                       RadiusX="0,100"
                       RadiusY="0,55">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush 
                        x:Name="GreenBlockGradient"
                        GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                        Center="0.5,0.5"
                        RadiusX="0.5"
                        RadiusY="0.5"
                        Opacity="0">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"
                                      x:Name="WhiteStop2"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1.9"
                                       x:Name="GreenStop"/>

                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>


            <!--GRADIENT SECTION-->
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                       Fill="Red"
                        RadiusX="0,100"
                       RadiusY="0,55"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                       Name="RedBlock"
                       RadiusX="0,100"
                       RadiusY="0,55">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush 
                        x:Name="RedBlockGradient"
                        GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                        Center="0.5,0.5"
                        RadiusX="0.5"
                        RadiusY="0.5"
                        Opacity="0">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"
                                      x:Name="WhiteStop"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.9"
                                       x:Name="RedStop"/>

                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>


            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="LightBlue"
                       RadiusX="100"
                       RadiusY="100"
                       Name="ScoreRectangle"/>
            <TextBlock Text="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="50"
                       FontFamily="Nexa Demo"
                       Name="Score"
                       Foreground="White"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button Content="PLAY" FontFamily="Nexa Demo" 
                Width="200" Height="90" FontSize="50
                " BorderBrush="LightBlue" 
                Margin="290,30,950,0"

                Name="PlayButton"
                Background="Transparent"
                BorderThickness="9"

                />

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: The thing is that in the XAML creator it resizes easily, but I need to figure out a way to resize the grid when the user resizes the window.

Comment: grid has fixed size: `<Grid Width="777" Height="777">`. remove it to get adaptive layout.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer sir. I've tried to do that but then the application messes up, maybe you can help me by pasting my code into XAML or something.

Comment: When I remove it it looks like this https://imgur.com/a/CnZq8Ow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your outer StackPanel inside a Viewbox:

```
<Viewbox>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White" ...>
        ... etc ...
    </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```